# How to Use Union And Paginate in laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination, eloquent, union

I Want To Union two Model And Paginate Result But Get Error, In Bellow See My Call Code And Result:

```
$this->archive = $this->archive
        ->select (['id','property_id','plan_id','pay_id','price','period','start_at','expire_at'])
        ->whereHas('property',function ($query) use ($user){
        $query->select(['user_id','type_id','title'])->where('user_id',$user);
        })->with(['property'=>function($query){
            $query->select('title','id');
        },'property.owner'=>function($query){
            $query->select('name','family','id');
        },'plan'=>function($query){
            $query->select('title','price','id','status');
        },'transaction'=>function($query){
            $query->select('port','price','id','status','payment_date');
        }]);
    $this->model = $this->model
        ->select (['id', 'property_id','plan_id','pay_id','price','period','start_at','expire_at'])
        ->whereHas('property',function ($query) use ($user){
        $query->select(['user_id','type_id','title'])->where('user_id',$user);
        })->with(['property'=>function($query){
            $query->select('title','id');
        },'property.owner'=>function($query){
            $query->select('name','family','id');
        },'plan'=>function($query){
            $query->select('title','price','id','status');
        },'transaction'=>function($query){
            $query->select('port','price','id','status','payment_date');
        }])
        ->union($this->archive)->orderBy('expire_at','DESC')->paginate ($paginate);
```

And Result Of Them Is:

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

Please Help Me

Answer (score 1):

you can union sql results like this,

```
$result = $query1->merge($query2);

        $resultSorted = $result->sortByDesc('expire_at');

        $count = $query1->count() + $query2->count();
        $page = $request['page'];
        $perPage = 20;

        $resultSorted = new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $resultSorted->forPage($page, $perPage), $count, $perPage, $page
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination with union is [not supported](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21958) in Laravel since there's no elegant way to do it without major drawbacks.